# R code for reading Excel in character format

Tags: r, openxlsx, excel-import

I am trying to open an Excel dataset in R studio, exactly how it looks in Excel, so I can learn how to manipulate it in different ways within R studio, rather than doing prep via Excel first. I am essentially trying a blind practical self teaching of R, with no prior coding knowledge and see this as a good way to figure my way around R. The issue I am having is that some of the format of the data has translated differently in R (for example, a filename extension of 8.7 in Excel coming through as 8.6666529999776429). I have tried to work around this, but it has just made all cells have the correct numbers but with the same number of decimal places, which is still not what I need, and I am now stumped as to how I need to adapt my open.xlsx read code to have it match exactly what Excel shows.

I have been able to read my Excel file into R studio using openxlsx package and with the following code:

```
read.xlsx('*filepath*.xlsx', sheet = "overview", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, detectDates = FALSE, skipEmptyRows = TRUE, skipEmptyCols = TRUE, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, check.names = FALSE, sep.names = " ", namedRegion = NULL, na.strings = NA, fillMergedCells = FALSE,
```

followed by:

```
data<- read.xlsx('*filepath*.xlsx', sheet = "overview", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, detectDates = FALSE, skipEmptyRows = TRUE, skipEmptyCols = TRUE, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, check.names = FALSE, sep.names = " ", namedRegion = NULL, na.strings = NA, fillMergedCells = FALSE)
```

But when I look at the table it has imported the format of some numbers in the 'Filename extension' column incorrectly. I have added the following code:

```
#reframing the column for numeric setting in the same format as the source

column_name <- 'Filename extension'

#setting the Filename extension column as numeric

data[[column_name]] <- as.numeric(data[[column_name]])
```

But this has added decimal places where they are not needed as I want the filename numbers as they are presented in Excel. For example, the left column here shows Excel, and the right column shows what R presents.

| Excel | R Studio |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.00 |
| 2.1 | 2.10 |
| 3.2 | 3.20 |
| 10.9 | 10.90 |
| 11.10 | 11.10 |
| 12.11 | 12.11 |

I want to present the filenames correctly and have read that I need to change the column classes to 'character', after which I can then assign that particular column as above, and this should retain the numbers in that column exactly as they are in the excel sheet. I have tried several variations of code in which I have added colClasses arguments to the end of my read_xlsx code, but each time I get the error showing the colClasses as an unused argument. I've also added 'as.data.frame = TRUE alongside the colClasses and had the same response. What am I doing wrong? And will this colClasses addition actually get me to my desired end result? I am massively new to R studio and coding, so explanations in great detail would be fantastic as I'm getting most of my code from pages like this, or chatGPT, so it's very much a trial and error learning process for me.

Comment: you could put the type of each column:
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("tu_archivo.xlsx", col_types = c("character", "numeric", "numeric"))

Comment: can you please explain what the c represents? and does the information within the brackets outline what each column should be going left to right? Sorry, I really have limited knowledge so I am struggling to understand the reasoning for the addition and how I can apply it to my situation

Comment: Dont worry about that. In R we use c() for create a vector of strings. So, when you need concatenate use c("character", "numeric", "numeric"), but in this case depend the order of your Excel column and you could add more columns in this order.

Comment: It still comes back as an unused argument, rather frustratingly

Comment: Change for c("text", "numeric", "numeric"). The idea is load like character for avoid extra number 00.